# Are Temper match cases order dependent

Tags: match, temper

```
match (x) {
  is Foo -> handleFoo(x);
  is Bar -> handleBar(x);
}
```

If *Bar extends Foo*, would that make the *handleBar* case unreachable?

Or is there some notion of specificity that controls here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently implemented, the order matters. Think of it as an `if`/`else if` sequence. Since Temper still isn't 1.0, this behavior could perhaps change in the future. There haven't been enough formal discussions on it.

Comment: So treat it as if/else, test thoroughly, so if it changes I'll know.

Comment: It will be nice to stabilize more as we go along.